# Multithreaded Hibernate Session

Tags: multithreading, hibernate

I've got an issue involving scheduled tasks and Hibernate. I'm trying to use the java `Timer` object to schedule a task to run once a second. That tasks involves querying a database via hibernate. Now, as far as I understand it, Hibernate `getCurrentSession()` method will return a session bound to the current context.

Firstly, I am using this code to schedule the task:

```
  timer = new Timer();
  task = new UpdateTask();
  // Schedule the task for future runs.
  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
```

The code for the task is as follows:

```
 public void run() {
    FilterMeetingDao fmService = new FilterMeetingDao();
    Set<String> codes = new HashSet<String>();

    String date = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT).format(new Date());
    try {
        List<Meeting> meetings = new MeetingDao().getMeetings(date);

        for(Meeting m : meetings)
        {
             if(RawMeetingFilter.isDefaultMeeting(m)) {
                  // Is a default meeting. Insert into the database.
                  codes.add(m.getCode());
             }
        }
        fmService.add(codes, date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the code is the `DAO` object that is retrieving the information:

```
public List<Meeting> getMeetings(String date) throws ParseException{                        
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);         
    Date startDate = sdf.parse(date);

    Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Meeting m where m.startDate = :startDate and source not like 'TTV' order by countrycode, categorycode, description");
    query.setParameter("startDate", startDate);     
    return query.list();
}
```

And the `getSession` method is the origin of the NPE, which is as follows:

```
public Session getSession(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

The line `return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` is the origin of the error. Now, this obviously means the `sessionFactory` is null. However, in my code, the exact *same* database request is made in the previous line. This tells me that the `sessionFactory` isn't null because the previous request is successful.

Here is a stack trace of the `NullPointerException`:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sis.rawfilter.dao.impl.BaseDao.getSession(BaseDao.java:13)
at com.sis.rawfilter.dao.impl.MeetingDao.getMeetings(MeetingDao.java:21)
at com.sis.rawfilter.domain.UpdateTask.run(UpdateTask.java:32)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

**Just for reference..**

```
meetings = meetingService.getMeetings(date);
// meetingService is the wrapper for the DAO object. this is the successful request.
```

And this is how I start my request:

```
 us.startTimer();
```

Which starts off the call chain, with the `timer` code at the top.

**Edits I've made to try and fix it**

So I added in a new `bean` tag into the `applicationContext.xml` file. That looks like this:

```
 <bean id="updateTask" class="com.sis.rawfilter.domain.UpdateTask"/>
```

And I've added in the `Autowired` tag into the class for the fields:

```
@Autowired
private IMeetingService meetingService;

@Autowired
private IFilterMeetingService filterMeetingService;
```

These types are declared in the applicationContext file as:

```
<bean id="meetingService" class="com.sis.rawfilter.service.impl.MeetingService"/>
<bean id="filterMeetingService" class="com.sis.rawfilter.service.impl.FilterMeetingService"/>
```

**Sample Service Class**

```
@Transactional
public class FilterMeetingService implements IFilterMeetingService {

@Autowired
private IFilterMeetingDao filterMeetingDao;

public List<FilterMeeting> getFilterMeetings(String date) throws ParseException{
    return filterMeetingDao.getFilterMeetings(date);
}

public void save(Set<String> selectedMeetings, Set<String> excludedMeetings, String date) throws ParseException{    

    if(excludedMeetings.size() > 0){
        filterMeetingDao.remove(excludedMeetings, date);
    }

    if(selectedMeetings.size() > 0){
        filterMeetingDao.add(selectedMeetings, date);
    }
}

public void setFilterMeetingDao(IFilterMeetingDao filterMeetingDao) {
    this.filterMeetingDao = filterMeetingDao;
}

}
```

**Sample Dao Class**

```
public class FilterMeetingDao extends BaseDao implements IFilterMeetingDao {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<FilterMeeting> getFilterMeetings(String date) throws ParseException{    

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);         
    Date startDate = sdf.parse(date);

    Query query = getSession().createQuery("from FilterMeeting fm where fm.startDate = :startDate");
    query.setParameter("startDate", startDate);

    return query.list();        
}


public void remove(Set<String> codes, String date){

    Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("delete from tbl where d = :date and c in :codes ");
    query.setParameter("date", date);
    query.setParameterList("codes", codes);
    query.executeUpdate();
}

public void add(Set<String> codes, String date) throws ParseException{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT); 

    for(String code : codes){
        FilterMeeting filterMeeting = new FilterMeeting(code,   sdf.parse(date), Config.getInstance().getQueue());
        getSession().save(filterMeeting);   
    }
}

}
```

Comment: You're using Spring or some other dependency injection framework, right? Show us the code of the DAO and the service.

Comment: I am. My boss just explained it to me. I've never used Spring before, so he just ran me through the basic overview. I think @commit answer is probably correct. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: Then ask your boss to explain this issue, because you missed some important aspects. When you instantiate an object using new, Spring is not aware of it, and can't magically inject the session factory inside the DAO. Moreover, the time should call a transactional service, and not a DAO directly.

Comment: He has explained the issue, and as I just said, I'll give it a go. The only reason I asked was because I was ignorant of Spring. Now I am not. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new object of meeting dao

```
new MeetingDao().getMeetings(date);
```

so `sessionFactory` object will not initialize and obviously you will get `nullPointerException`, you should `Autowired` dao.

Comment: I'll give this a go now. bare with me a few moments!

Comment: I added the `@Autowired` annotation, and added a definition of the class as a `bean` to the applicationContext.xml file. The `MeetingDao` class has already been defined as a bean in there so I'm under the impression it should work? It's not throwing any errors; it's just leading MeetingDao null.

Comment: Your Dao is not bean, you should defined it as `Service` or `Component` and you need to also autowire your sessionfactory object by initializing init method.

Comment: The sessionFactory object is not the issue. I apologise. It's the `MeetingService` class (a wrapper for the Dao) that has been defined as a `bean`. I'll amend my code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Have you also autowired dao in your service class? and still I did not understand why you have declare your service class as bean(is your service class is POJO?), please show your code of service class and dao.

Comment: Both the `FilterMeetingService` and the `MeetingService` class have their respecting `Dao` objects, and they are both `Autowired`. Neither do I; this isn't my project. I'm just trying to make sense of it!

Comment: Edited in a sample of the Dao class and the service class.

Comment: Your code seems fine, make sure you also get records by firing that query in database manually.

Comment: Just had another play. Turned out the app that I was usnig to schedule and run the task was declared via the `new` operator. Obviously, this means that Spring wasn't managing it, so it wasn't processing any of the `@Autowired` annotations. After making the scheduling class a Spring dependency, it's worked perfectly. Thankyou for all of the help!!